# changing string to date field in rails mysql

Tags: mysql, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanna convert a data type from string to date format. I am using mysql database. The values are stored in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. If I try to convert the string to date using `.to_date` function for date values like "02/28/2017", it is throwing invalid date error. So, I decided to convert the datatype. Suppose if I convert the datatype using migration what happens to the existing records?
All the records are important. What should I do now?

```
rails g migration change_date_format_in_my_table

class ChangeDateFormatInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :date
  end

  def down
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: I would keep the string format, have a look there I am not sure what you really want to do, but in this doc you may find what you need
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

Comment: Will check @Nelly. Thanks for your time.